# Devexpress GridControl columns stop resize

Tags: winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

For a GridView in winforms, DevExpress:

I need to stop auto resize columns in a GridControl.
Example:
If I have 3 columns: 100, 200, 150​
then if I resize first column to 50 then the ​difference will be shared with second and third columns. This also happens if I increase width.
So I must stop this process. What tools do I have in order to make this.
Thanks. Hope  you understood.
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop AutoColumnWidth:

```
gridView.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false
```